# Beginner SQL Single-row subquery returns more than one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hey guys stuck on this question:

Show all film titles and dvd numbers. Sort by film title and dvd #. Make is so that the film title is not repeated in the output.

Film_title comes from a table named cp_title and dvd_number comes from a table name cp_dvd. This is what I have come up with:

```
select film_title, dvd_number
from cp_title
join cp_dvd using(title_code)
where film_title =
(select unique film_title
from cp_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, near `where` clause your are selecting all rows from `cp_title`

```
where film_title =(select unique film_title from cp_title)
```

`where` clause expects single row value whereas your `cp_title` table will returns multiple value and that's why you are getting this error.

I'm not sure, what you are trying to achieve from your query, but assuming you need unique set of `film_title, dvd_number`. Then simply you can use `distinct`

```
select distinct film_title, dvd_number from cp_title join cp_dvd using(title_code)
```

Comment: By doing this the film title is repeated in the output

Comment: could you provide your table data and expected output and actual output ?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
select unique film_title
from cp_title
```

is returning multiple rows then you cannot check for quality

Perhaps you meant

```
select film_title, dvd_number
from cp_title
join cp_dvd using(title_code)
where film_title IN
(select unique film_title
from cp_title);
```

[image]

Comment: @DNkG you'll need to provide sample input and output so we can understand your question.

Comment: just added a picture. the list of film titles should only show one of each.

Comment: @DNkG And what should it show for the DVD_NUMBER if there are multiple of the same title?

Comment: Good question. Honestly this was a practice question for an exam i have in a few days. I'm guessing just one dvd number(maybe the first) for the unique film title column. Is that why im getting that error in my sub query because the dvd number column has multiple rows associated with a film title?